# htaccess not working for www and non-www

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i'm trying to redirect *www.site.ru* and *site.ru* to *www.site.ru/ru_RU*. But i can't make it work.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site\.ru$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.site.ru/ru_RU [L,R]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.site\.ru$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.site.ru/ru_RU [L,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/news
RewriteRule (.*) /news [QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?page=$1 [QSA]
</IfModule>
```

It's not redirecting WWW version. Can someone tell me how to make that request. By the way, sometimes i come to situation, where in firefox it's working, but in IE it's not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?site\.ru$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.site.ru/ru_RU [L,R]

## WHAT IS THIS RULE DOING??
# RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/news
# RewriteRule ^ /news [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]

</IfModule>
```

btw I had to comment out suspicious looking 2nd rule for `/news`. If you can explain what you're trying to do with this I can suggest you how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/ru_RU [R=permanent,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/ru_RU [R=301,L]
```